# Flutter: How to use dart-define variables in gradle scripts

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

While creating integration tests for a flutter app, how to pass a `dart-define` variables via gradle scripts.

From Flutter documentation, in order to build an instrumentation test apk (and later to upload it to Firebase test lab and test), we need to directly use `gradlew` commands like this:

```
pushd android
flutter build apk
./gradlew app:assembleAndroidTest
./gradlew app:assembleDebug -Ptarget=integration_test/<name>_test.dart
popd
```

Here its not specified how to pass `--dart-define` flag's content that we are using from flutter side `flutter run` to the `gradlew` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flutter `dart-define` flag is encoded to base64, and passed to gradle as comma separated fields with an argument name `-Pdart-defines`. So we can utilise this to manually pass `dart-define` variables

Consider that your dart-define flag is `environment=staging`

Then on normal flutter run, you will be using it like this.

```
flutter run --dart-define environment=staging
```

To pass this via `gradlew` command, convert it into base64 encoded string and pass it like below.

Base64 encoded string of `environment=staging` is `ZW52aXJvbm1lbnQ9c3RhZ2luZw==`

So use

```
./gradlew app:assembleDebug -Ptarget=integration_test/<name>_test.dart -Pdart-defines="ZW52aXJvbm1lbnQ9c3RhZ2luZw=="
```

If you have multiple dart defines, add them separated by comma. (note that the flag is -Pdart-defines - (the define`s` clarifies it) )

```
./gradlew app:assembleDebug -Ptarget=integration_test/<name>_test.dart -Pdart-defines="ZW52aXJvbm1lbnQ9c3RhZ2luZw==,ZW1haWw9bXllbWFpbEBlbWFpbC5jb20="
```